# request_firmware_nowait failure while loading driver (fw)

Tags: linux, embedded, linux-device-driver

I am trying to load some driver module which has firmware. This driver is trying to push fw image to hardware through remoteproc.

`rproc_add` is calling "request_firmware_nowait" and I encountered "-2" error at `fw_get_filesystem_firmware()` API.

It seems that file not found but, before I call `insmod`, I double checked path name and everything and it seems to be fine. Even permission looks good.

If I call direct firmware load call (changed kernel source code) and at least, it was able to find the file.

Any clue on this? It seems that we are failing `filp_open` inside `fw_get_filesystem_firmware` function and this operation is working on top of `workqueue`.

Any information will be welcomed!

- Linux kernel 4.4.46
- Early stage boot up
- Using `initrd` and everything is on `ramfs` (squashfs)
- from the workqueue, we call `request_firmware`

Comment: Show us the exact absolute path to the firmware file and its name.

Comment: Sorry. It is under /lib/firmware but I cannot tell the exact path.
it is like /lib/firmware/XXX0123/a0_xxx.xx

We checked permission (755) and max path length and everything seems to be good. Also, our initrd image has firmware file too. (from the user-space, we can access the file but it is only failing from kernel side (filp_open)).